# check if user is logged in ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

i want check in appdelegate.swift file  if user logged in showing HomeviewController like Instagram  and  if not Showing LoginViewController , iam using mysql to save users data and php  bridge lang

code in appdalegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

         var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
         let isUserLoggedIn:Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")
         if(isUserLoggedIn) {
         let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
         let protectedPage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("goToHome") as! HomeViewController
         window!.rootViewController = protectedPage
         window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
         }
         else{
         let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
         let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginview") as! LoginViewController
         window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
         window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


         }


        return true
    }
```

loginviewcontoler.swift

```
let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                        //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                        NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                        if(success == 1)
                        {
                            NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                            let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                            prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                            prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                            prefs.synchronize()


                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToHome", sender: self)
```

ProfileViewController.swift

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)


        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int


        if (isLoggedIn != 1) {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)

        }

        else
        {

            self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String

        }

    }
```

sorry for long question

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: not issue but i want user when open app check if logged in showing loginview else showing loginview (like cookies or somting like that  @JigarTarsariya)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use in this situation NSUserDefaults

https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Here is good example of using safe LogIn / LogOut
so, after implementation

```
if let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("accaunt")
{
//go to profile
}
 else
{
//go to login
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Follow step**:-

Step 1 :- Create `custom SplashViewController` set rootViewController  `SplashViewController`

Step 2 :- Write login service call on `SplashViewController`
Setp 3 :- When you get Login success then just change `rootViewController`
Setp 4 :- Write one method in `AppDelegate` For change `rootViewController` for redirect `Homescreen`. 
Setp 5 :- Call `AppDelegate` method for go to `Homescreen`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do some works.
1. You have to make sure that the user is logged in. to do that when you press the button (login button) use UserDefaults

```
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
userDefault.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
userDefault.synchronize()
```

2.When user will launch the app again just check whether the user logged in or not in viewDidAppear method/ viewDidLoad(its your choice which method you will use. most of the time I use viewDidAppear)

```
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

let savedData = userDefault.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
if(savedData){
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTest", sender:nil)//here u have decide the which view will show if the user is logged in how. here i used   segue.

}else{
   viewController = self// this is the main view. just make the object of the class and called it.
}
```

I hope you know how to prepare segue

Answer (score -2):

Just a concise way of doing the same thing:

```
func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // present login controller
            let loginVC = LoginVC()
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return
    }
}
```